# docker build suddenly freezes while installing openjdk8 (at step 'Installing nss')

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I was a building a docker image that compiles and executes java server program. I was using openjdk8 with alpine linux. Usually i never have problems building the image from this Dockerfile and everything works fine. But now it suddenly freezes at 'Installing nss (3.44-r0)' while trying to install openjdk8.

Cant really figure out what to try because this usually works for me but i've tried removing the existing containers and images and tried a fresh build. Even tried reinstalling docker.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /root/server_dir
COPY src/ /root/server_dir
COPY server_dir/ /root/server_dir
# Install JDK
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/*
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add openjdk8 
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
# Compile and run
RUN javac Server.java 
ENTRYPOINT java Server
```

Now if i enter the build command :

```
docker build -t server-image .
```

This is what i get,

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.29kB
Step 1/11 : FROM alpine
 ---> 961769676411
Step 2/11 : WORKDIR /root/server_dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f4d35877ace0
Step 3/11 : COPY src/ /root/server_dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f03951c404d
Step 4/11 : COPY server_dir/ /root/server_dir
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e050ff9f9a5
Step 5/11 : RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 501199e8b113
Step 6/11 : RUN apk update && apk upgrade
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f477837d631e
Step 7/11 : RUN apk add openjdk8
 ---> Running in 542d0347c711
(1/40) Installing libffi (3.2.1-r6)
(2/40) Installing p11-kit (0.23.16.1-r0)
(3/40) Installing libtasn1 (4.14-r0)
(4/40) Installing p11-kit-trust (0.23.16.1-r0)
(5/40) Installing ca-certificates (20190108-r0)
(6/40) Installing java-cacerts (1.0-r0)
(7/40) Installing libgcc (8.3.0-r0)
(8/40) Installing nspr (4.20-r0)
(9/40) Installing sqlite-libs (3.28.0-r0)
(10/40) Installing libstdc++ (8.3.0-r0)
(11/40) Installing nss (3.44-r0)
```

As you can see everything up to this works fine, then it just freezes for hours

Comment: Got disk space?

Comment: That may be caused by many things. Some ideas : 1) Try to inspect the layer that failed (nss) 2) if possible remove all downloaded layers and start again.  Maybe a cache issue 3) check the network activity.

Comment: Got disk space @masseyb.

Comment: network is fine,shouldnt reinstalling docker and the docker machine remove all downloaded layers ? @davidxxx

Comment: You can get more info by following commands: 
`docker image ls` identify your partly built image `docker image history <ID>`  then create a container from any point inside your image. And `docker run -it --rm <ID> sh`. At this point you can run your next build commands. (For more info have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567767/docker-build-hangs-how-can-i-see-what-is-going-on] )

Comment: Any reason to not use the official OpenJDK8 image?